# Calibrating IMUs

Tags: navigation, clearpath, husky, microstrain, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Community,

I now have 3 IMUs installed on my Clearpath Husky. The IMUs are a Microstrain 3DM-GX2, a Microstrain 3DM-GX3, and a Microstrain 3DM-GX4. The 3DM-GX2 and 3DM-GX3 both use the 3DM-GX2 node: http://wiki.ros.org/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu

The 3DM-GX4 uses its namesake node, found here: https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4

How do I calibrate the 3DM-GX3 and 3DM-GX4 IMUs? I will need step-by-step instructions as I am very new to working with hardware.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220791/calibrating-imus/) by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Husky has an IMU calibration tool in the `scripts` directory:

http://wiki.ros.org/husky_bringup

You can also hook the IMUs up (while still on the robot) to a laptop running Windows and use Microstrain's own software to do calibration; the calibration parameters are then stored directly on the IMU itself.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0